# Minesweeper Tile Value Issue

Tags: java

I am currently coding a Minesweeper game to learn a bit more about using objects in my code. The way that I am generating the board is:

- Create a 2d array of "Tile" objects of a specified number of rows and columns
- Tile objects store a value (the number of adjacent bombs, or 9 if bomb), a boolean to represent if the tile has been clicked or not (important for the behavior of clearing multiple tiles at once if you click a tile that is not adjacent to any bombs), and a button for the graphical representation of the tile
- First, the board is set up by setting all Tile values to 0.
- Then, in a while loop, bombs are randomly distributed onto the board.
- When a bomb is successfully placed, all adjacent non-bomb Tile values are increased by 1. Bound errors are avoided with a method that takes the row + column coordinates to determine if the area exists on the board.
- This process is repeated until all bombs have been placed.

**My problem:**

After the board successfully generates, there are occasional tiles which have an incorrect value, generally 1 less than they should be. Often a "1" or "2" tile that should be a "2" or "3" tile. There is no pattern to this which I can discern, which makes it rather frustrating. I'm sure that I could structure my code differently, such as iterating through the board and adding numerical values after every bomb has been placed, but that isn't really how I want to do it. I think this way is cooler.

I have removed the graphical stuff because it isn't necessary for this problem, and I think this is already a lengthy bit of code to post in a question on here. You should be able to paste it into your IDE and have it run fine, and the game boards will be output to your console.

I have the boards set up to 5x5, with 5 bombs, although this issue persists across all board sizes and bomb densities. This issue is not super frequent, and doesn't appear on every single board. I generally see it after 2-3 runs of the program on a board this size, so be prepared for that.

Here is an example image, for anyone who does not wish to open up their IDE. As you can see, the "1" tiles is adjacent to 2 bombs:

[image: Minesweeper Error]

But without further ado, here is my code. Thanks!

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board(5, 5, 5);
        board.setupBoard();
        board.printBoard();
    }
}

class Board {
    /*
     * height: the height of the game board (in Tiles)
     * width: the width of the game board (in Tiles)
     * bombs: the total number of bombs to be spawned
     * tiles: 2d array of Tile objects, which store
     *      important game information
     */
    private int rows, cols, bombs;
    private Tile[][] tiles;
    /*
     * Constructor - assigns values to height, width and bombs
     */
    Board(int rows, int cols, int bombs) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.bombs = bombs;
        tiles = new Tile[rows][cols];
    }
    Tile[][] getTiles() {
        return tiles;
    }
    /*
     * Iterates tiles adjacent to bomb tile if:
     *      - Tile is not a bomb
     *      - Tile exists
     */
    private void bombIterate(int y, int x) {
        if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < cols && y < rows && tiles[y][x].getValue() != 9) {
            tiles[y][x].setValue(tiles[y][x].getValue() + 1);
        }
    }
    /*
     * Determines if a tile exists or not to easier avoid bound errors
     */
    boolean validClick(int y, int x) {
        if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < cols && y < rows && tiles[y][x].getValue() != 9
                && !tiles[y][x].isClicked()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /*
     * Sets up all bombs and tile values
     */
    void setupBoard() {
        /*
         * Initializes the game board with 0's
         */
        for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
                tiles[y][x] = new Tile(0);
            }
        }
        /*
         * Randomly distributes bombs to the game board
         */
        int randRow; int randCol;
        while(bombs > 0) {
            randRow = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, rows);
            randCol = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, cols);
            if(tiles[randRow][randCol].getValue() != 9) {
                tiles[randRow][randCol].setValue(9);
                /*
                 * Iterate tile values around placed bomb
                 */
                for(int y = randRow - 1; y < randRow + 2; y++) {
                    for(int x = randCol - 1; x < randCol + 2; x++) {
                        if(y != randCol || x != randRow) {
                            bombIterate(y, x);
                        }
                    }
                }
                bombs--;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * Prints the game board (to console)
     */
    void printBoard() {
        for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
                System.out.print(tiles[y][x].getValue() + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Tile {
    /*
     * value = the numerical value of the tile
     *      9 = bomb, 0-8 = number of adjacent bombs
     *
     * clicked = boolean - represents if the tile has
     *     been interacted with yet
     *
     * button = the GUI button that is linked to
     *      the tile
     */
    private int value;
    private boolean clicked;

    Tile(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.clicked = false;
    }

    /*
     * Sets a tile's "clicked" value to true/false
     */
    void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
    }

    /*
     * Returns if the tile has been clicked or not
     */
    boolean isClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the tile's value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /*
     * Used to set the tile's value to a new integer
     */
    void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pat It looks like you did a pretty good job minimizing your code that demonstrates your issue.  You've done more than most do to ask a good question.  Perhaps you could include sample incorrect output and where in the code you think the bug is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is messed up here:

```
           for(int y = randRow - 1; y < randRow + 2; y++) {
                for(int x = randCol - 1; x < randCol + 2; x++) {
                    if(y != randCol || x != randRow) {
                        bombIterate(y, x);
                    }
                }
            }
```

You are using `y` for rows, but test `y != randCol`.  Similar problem with `x` and `x != randRow`.